# Want to hide status bar just in launchscreen in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

Want to hide status bar just in launchscreen in iOS?
in other storyboards it should be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply check `Hide status bar` in your target's general settings. This should hide your status bar on the launch screen but show it on the initial viewcontroller.

Comment: it worked. Thank you.

Comment: This option hides the status bar for the whole app.